# File .log with "Could not load configuration: Failed to load configuration" VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, visual-studio-code, activestate

I'm wondering and trying to figure out why every time that I open a `.py` file in an open folder in the VScode an untracked `.log` file is generated with the following output:

```
[ERROR Apr 30 13:58:07.394495100, defaults.go:139] Could not load configuration: Failed to load configuration.

Stacktrace: D:/a/cli/cli/internal/logging/logging.go:github.com/ActiveState/cli/internal/logging.Error:258
D:/a/cli/cli/internal/logging/defaults.go:github.com/ActiveState/cli/internal/logging.init.0:139
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/go/1.15.11/x64/src/runtime/proc.go:runtime.doInit:5652
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/go/1.15.11/x64/src/runtime/proc.go:runtime.doInit:5647
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/go/1.15.11/x64/src/runtime/proc.go:runtime.doInit:5647
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/go/1.15.11/x64/src/runtime/proc.go:runtime.main:191
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/go/1.15.11/x64/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:runtime.goexit:1374

[DEBUG Apr 30 13:58:07.423479400, locale.go:34] Init
```

There is no big problem because the `.py` files run perfectly but it's really exhausting to delete  the `.log` file all the time.

Thanks!

Comment: Reinstalling the VSCode doesn't work!

Comment: Reinstalling a tool rarely works these days. Too many store their configuration in a location that survives the reinstall, leaving you no better off.

Comment: @drescherjm  wonderful! I resolved the question uninstalling the extension "ActiveState Platform" in the VSCode. Thanks a lot! #vscode

Comment: I removed my comment because after commenting I googled for ActiveState python and the error message and it did not appear to have any hits so I thought I was going down the wrong path..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the question uninstalling the extension "ActiveState Platform" in the VSCode.